# If $ f $ and $ g $ are similar endomorphism iff $ f $ and $ g $ are represented by the same matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If E is a $ \mathbb {C} $-vector space, we denote by $ \mathcal {L} (E) $ the $ \mathbb {C} $-algebra of endomorphisms of $ E $.
Let $ E $ and $ F $ be two $ \mathbb {C} $-vector spaces of the same finite dimension $ n \geq 1 $ and $ f \in \mathcal {L} (E) $ and $ g \in \mathcal {L} (F) $

> **Definition**: we say that f and g are *similar* if there exists an isomorphism $ u $ from $ E $ in $ F $ satisfying: $ g = u \circ f \circ u^ {- 1} $. We denote by $ f \mathcal {R} g $.

Thus $ \mathcal {R} $ is an equivalence relation over the set of all endomorphisms of vector spaces of dimension $ n $ over $ \mathbb {C} $.

**Problem:**

Show that  $ f \mathcal {R} g $ if and only if : there exists  a base $ \mathcal {B} $ of $ E $ and a base $ \mathcal {C} $ of $ F $ such that:
$$
mat_ {\mathcal {B}} (f) = mat_ {\mathcal {C}} (g) \qquad (mat_ {\mathcal {B}} (f) \text { denotes the matrix of  } f \text {  relatively at the base } \mathcal {B})
$$
in other words, $ f $ and $ g $ are represented by the same matrix.

An idea please.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Just asking the question and showing no work is not how this site works. What do you know about representing a linear transformation  using different bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch of Proof:** To begin, prove that if $f,g$ are represented by the same matrix, then $f$ and $g$ are similar. To me, this is the "easier" direction.

Let $M$ denote this common matrix, which is the matrix of $f$ relative to $\mathcal B$ and the matrix of $g$ relative to $\mathcal C$. Note that $M$ can be thought of as a linear map $M:\Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C^n$. Corresponding to our choice of basis $\mathcal B$, I claim that there exists an invertible linear map $\beta:\Bbb C^n \to E$ for which
$$
M = \beta^{-1} \circ f \circ \beta.
$$
What exactly is this map? That is, how should this map be defined in terms of the elements of $\mathcal B$? For the same reason, we can write $M = \gamma^{-1} \circ g \circ \gamma$ for an invertible $\gamma:\Bbb C^n \to F$. With that, we find
$$
\beta^{-1} \circ f \circ \beta = \gamma^{-1} \circ g \circ \gamma \implies\\
\gamma \circ \beta^{-1} \circ f \circ \beta \circ \gamma^{-1} = g \implies\\
u \circ f \circ u^{-1} = g,
$$
where $u = \gamma \circ \beta^{-1}$.

For the converse implication, we are given that $g = u \circ f \circ u^{-1}$. I claim that there exist invertible maps $\beta : \Bbb C^n \to E$ and $\gamma : \Bbb C^n \to F$ such that $u = \gamma \circ \beta^{-1}$. With the first half of the proof in mind, use this to conclude that $f$ and $g$ are represented by the same matrix $M$ relative to some choice of basis $\mathcal B$ of $E$ and $\mathcal C$ of $F$.